# Classification with huge testing

Tags: bigdata, classification, simulation

I am currently trying to solve a classification problem, which should later be running on a simulation environment. That means it gets the data from multiple events and should assign the data into one class or the other in real time. The simulation will run for 1d in simulation time and afterwards the algorithm will be evaluated on that.
For the training portion of the algorithm I use different parts of the day as one day has 64 Million data points. I use only 3.5 Million (representative?), otherwise the training would be during to long and the data would be intransferable. The problem is that the Classifiers trained are pretty good when separating the 3.5 Million data points into training and test set (AUC of up to 0.9), but are very bad when used on the complete simulation environment. The False Positives go up to 10 times the True Positives.

Currently I am trying to fit a SVM, a MLP and a LSTM. Here is my code:

```
DataLoader:
Just load Data without any preprocessing or something like that
Data shape when LSTM is used:
X = (35000000,20,24)         -> All dense
y = (35000000,)

Data shape else:
X = (35000000,24)            -> All dense
y = (35000000,)
```

```
NetworkLibrary:

from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.svm import OneClassSVM
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import *
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.losses import BinaryCrossentropy
from keras.metrics import BinaryAccuracy

# from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
import numpy as np
import sys
import random

np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)


class NetworkLibrary:
    def __init__(self, seed) -> None:
        random.seed(seed)
        np.random.seed(seed)

    def get_trained_SVM(self, X_train, y_train, gamma, C):
        print("Starting machine learning SVM with")
        print("gamma: " + str(gamma))
        print("C: " + str(C))
        clf = SVC(gamma=gamma, C=C, verbose=1, probability=True)
        clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
        return clf

    def get_trained_MLP(
        self, X_train, y_train, hidden_layer, max_iter_no_change, max_iter
    ):
        print("Starting machine learning MLP with")
        print("Hidden layer: " + str(hidden_layer))
        print(
            "Maximal iterations without change in loss of 0.001: "
            + str(max_iter_no_change)
        )
        print("Maximal iterations of network training runs: " + str(max_iter))
        clf = MLPClassifier(
            hidden_layer_sizes=hidden_layer,
            n_iter_no_change=max_iter_no_change,
            max_iter=max_iter,
            verbose=True,
            solver="adam",
            random_state=1,
        )
        clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
        return clf

    def get_trained_LSTM(self, X_train, y_train, lstm_sizes, epochs):
        print("Starting machine learning LSTM with")
        print("LSTM layers: " + str(lstm_sizes))
        print("Number of epochs: " + str(epochs))
        clf = Sequential()
        lstm_size = len(lstm_sizes)
        (n_sample, n_features, time_steps) = np.shape(X_train)
        print(np.shape(y_train))
        for i in range(lstm_size):
            cur_size = lstm_sizes[i]
            if i == 0 and 1 == lstm_size:
                clf.add(
                    LSTM(
                        cur_size,
                        return_sequences=True,
                        input_shape=(n_features, time_steps),
                    )
                )
                clf.add(LSTM(cur_size, return_sequences=False))
                break
            elif i == 0:
                clf.add(
                    LSTM(
                        cur_size,
                        return_sequences=True,
                        input_shape=(n_features, time_steps),
                    )
                )
            elif i == (lstm_size - 1):
                clf.add(LSTM(cur_size, return_sequences=False))
            else:
                clf.add(LSTM(cur_size, return_sequences=True))
        clf.add(Dense(1))
        clf.compile(
            # Maybe here from_logits is not such a good alternative
            loss=BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
            optimizer=Adam(),
            metrics=[BinaryAccuracy()],
        )
        clf.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=epochs)
        return clf
```

```
MainClass:

from sklearn.utils.class_weight import compute_class_weight
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from NetworkTester import NetworkTester
from NetworkLibrary import NetworkLibrary
from DataLoader import *

import numpy as np
import joblib
import sys
import random
import math


random.seed(10)
np.random.seed(10)

np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)

# train_len = 1 / 10
train_len = 2 / 3
print_classes_and_coefs = False
max_grad = 4

if __name__ == "__main__":
    model = sys.argv[1]
    partition = sys.argv[2]
    negative_grad = -1 * math.log10(float(partition))
    ml_grad = max_grad - int(negative_grad)
    ml_grad_with_start = ml_grad + 2
    savePath = "/home/a/adamczykp/tmp/f2md-training/saveFile"
    library = NetworkLibrary(10)
    print("Starting...")
    if model.isdigit():
        model = int(model)
    else:
        model = model_name_to_number(model_name=model)
    X, y = collect_data_portion(model=model, check_version=1, partition=partition)
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
        X, y, train_size=train_len, random_state=2, stratify=y
    )
    class_weight = np.flip(compute_class_weight("balanced", classes=[0, 1], y=y))
    if model == 0:
        clf = library.get_trained_SVM(X_train, y_train, 0.001, 100.0)
        joblib.dump(clf, savePath + "/clfs/clf_SVM_SINGLE_" + partition + ".pkl")
    elif model == 1:
        hidden_layer = tuple([128 for _ in range(ml_grad)])
        n_iter_no_change = 500 * ml_grad
        max_iter = 15000 * ml_grad
        clf = library.get_trained_MLP(
            X_train, y_train, hidden_layer, n_iter_no_change, max_iter
        )
        joblib.dump(clf, savePath + "/clfs/clf_MLP_SINGLE_L1N25_" + partition + ".pkl")
    elif model == 2:
        hidden_layer = tuple([128 for _ in range(ml_grad_with_start)])
        n_iter_no_change = 500 * ml_grad_with_start
        max_iter = 15000 * ml_grad_with_start
        clf = library.get_trained_MLP(
            X_train, y_train, hidden_layer, n_iter_no_change, max_iter
        )
        joblib.dump(clf, savePath + "/clfs/clf_MLP_SINGLE_L3N25_" + partition + ".pkl")
    elif model == 3:
        hidden_layer = [128 for _ in range(ml_grad)]
        epochs = 500 * ml_grad
        clf = library.get_trained_LSTM(X_train, y_train, hidden_layer, epochs)
        joblib.dump(
            clf, savePath + "/clfs/clf_LSTM_RECURRENT_TIN_" + partition + ".pkl"
        )
    elif model == 4:
        hidden_layer = [128 for _ in range(ml_grad_with_start)]
        epochs = 500 * ml_grad_with_start
        clf = library.get_trained_LSTM(X_train, y_train, hidden_layer, epochs)
        joblib.dump(clf, savePath + "/clfs/clf_LSTM_RECURRENT_BIG_" + ".pkl")
    else:
        raise ValueError("Not a suitable model selected")
    if print_classes_and_coefs:
        print("Classes: " + str(clf.classes_) + "\n")
        print("Loss: " + str(round(clf.loss_, 4)) + "\n")
        for i in range(len(clf.coefs_)):
            print("----------Coef " + str(i) + ":----------\n")
            coef = clf.coefs_[i]
            print(str(coef) + "\n")
    ### Evaluate the model below here ###
```